# Conditionally insert a line in JSON array like file with awk

Tags: json, bash, awk, jq

I want to push items with `awk` to a `myArray.json` file like so

```
[
 item1,
 item2
]
```

To add item1 I tried

```
echo -e "[\n]" > myArray.json # Create an empty JSON array with "\n"
awk -v var="item1" '/\]/ {print var} 1' myArray.json >> myArray-tmp.json
mv myArray-tmp.json myArray.json
```

If I now comment out `echo -e "[\n]" > myArray.json` line (or conditionally skip it), set `var="item2"` and run the script, item2 is added to the array. **I want to add a comma after first line, but not second**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a possibly simpler alternative, you could just use `jq`. So, if you had the json file, `myArray.json`

```
[ "item1" ]
```

You can add additional elements simply with

```
jq '. + ["item2"]' myArray.json
```

which should result in

```
[
  "item1",
  "item2"
]
```

Comment: `. |= . + x` is the same as `. += x`, or just `. + x` for this case

Answer (score 1):

`jq` is a great tool so I upvoted and accepted answer. Here's my ugly way.

```
[
 item1
 ,item2
]
```

I needed to do conditional to skip first two lines after first item has been added. Run this line instead.

```
awk -v var="item2" '/\]/ {print ","var} 1' myArray.json >> myArray-tmp.json
```

Answer (score 1):

also, one easy alternative - a walk-path based unix utility **[`jtc`](https://github.com/ldn-softdev/jtc/blob/master/User%20Guide.md)** to manipulate json.

In `jtc` there's an option to apply changes right into the source file - `-f` (without it, the result will only be printed to the console):

```
bash $ jtc myArray.json 
[
   "item1"
]
bash $ 
bash $ jtc -f -i'"item2"' myArray.json 
bash $ 
bash $ jtc myArray.json 
[
   "item1",
   "item2"
]
bash $
```

Note: inserted element must be a valid JSON - hence double quotes (`”item2”` - that makes a valid JSON string) and to preserve them (escape shell interpolation) - there are outer single quotes around the argument

PS> Disclosure: I'm the creator of the `jtc` - shell cli tool for JSON operations